# Proguard rule for Huawei push client

Tags: android, proguard

I have `Unable to create application im.app.android.core.AppDemoApplication: e3.b: com.pushserver.android.huaweiPushClient cant cast com.myApp.android.push_lib.huawei.HcmPushClient to  PushClient` error

What proguard rule should I add? I have tried `-keep class com.myApp.android.push_lib.** { *; }` but after that I just see the blank screen - no crash, just stuck when trying to start.

Comment: Add your sdk version and gradle version

Comment: sdk 31. gradle-7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment. I'll update this answer in case we make progress.

#### 1. What is the "normal bug"?

`can't cast com.myApp.android.push_lib.huawei.HcmPushClient to PushClient`

This means that somewhere in your code you are assigning/passing an instance of `HcmPushClient` to something that is expecting it to be a `PushClient`. I would assume that `PushClient` is some class that you defined in your project, but is does not extend from `HcmPushClient`. Try to find this piece of code and fix it or add it here to your question.

#### 2. What does ProGuard have to do with this?

Actually, I think not much. If ProGuard would create this error, the message would look more like

`can't cast com.myApp.android.push_lib.a.b to c`

But since all class names in the error message are the original ones, it does not seem like ProGuard is making issues here. BUT: You can still decypher the message a little bit, because this part is obfuscated:

`Unable to create application im.app.android.core.AppDemoApplication: e3.b:`

`e3.b` refers to a class that was obfuscated by ProGuard. To find out what class it is, you can check the file `/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` in your project folder. This is a simple text file that stores the information what class name was renamed to what obfuscated name. In this file search for `-> e3` to find the class that was renamed to e3. Somewhere close to this line, you should also be able to find out what exactly `e3.b` is. Could be a method, could also be a member variable or an inner class.

I hope these two points will bring you closer to make the app run.

Comment: thanks for the response, but I have found the solution already. I just set "debuggable = false" for "release" version in gradle.